# Python loop runs once then creates 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file' error

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

New Python user here and I've recently met a problem which I can't seem to figure out. The code should do some web scraping on a specific site. It simply fetches one line of text on the site and writes it to a file with recent date. The problem is that it runs once or twice and produces 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.' error. I've tried this with threading and Advanced Python Scheduler with same error. What could be the problem, why the while loop won't keep running? Any help is appreciated :)

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf_8 -*-

import time
import os
import string
import sys,io
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

import config # Settings

def parseHeader(header):
    parseHeader.header = header[2:]
    parseHeader.header = parseHeader.header[:-1]

def fetchMedia():
    sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,'cp437','backslashreplace')
    r = requests.get(config.url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "popularBox"})

    for item in g_data:
        fetchMedia.header = item.text # Get latest media header from the website
        break

def saveMedia(header):
    with open(config.database,"w+") as db:
        db.seek(0)
        db.write(header + "\n" + time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") + " " + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            print("Stop program by pressing CTRL + C")
            print("Fetching the latest media header...")
            fetchMedia()
            parseHeader(fetchMedia.header)
            saveMedia(parseHeader.header)
            time.sleep(config.fetch_interval)
        except(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            pass
```

**config.py**

```
url = "https://www.riemurasia.net"
database = "db.txt"
fetch_interval = 10
```

**program output**

```
>> python main.py
Stop program by pressing CTRL + C
Fetching the latest media header...
Stop program by pressing CTRL + C
Fetching the latest media header...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
    print("Stop program by pressing CTRL + C")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: Please post the full error including stack trace.

Comment: Added program output including full error message. Thanks for notifying.